# Spring transactional tests. Nested transactions isn't rolled back

Tags: java, spring, oracle, transactions

I'm trying to implement integration tests using DbUnit + Spring(4.1.1) tests + MyBatis + Oracle

I'm doing the following:

1. Before test class: (a) Open transaction; 
   (b) Insert readonly common-parent dataset (for all test methods)
2. Mark test class as Transactional(propogation = NESTED). So each test method should be executed in its own transaction and then rollback it. Nested - because I want to have access to data inserted by "before test class" method in parent transaction (so propogation=REQUIRED_NEW is not an option)
3. After test class rollback parent transaction.

The problem is that nested transaction isn't rolled back. If Method A inserts data, Method B sees that data.

Could it be JDBC (11.2.0.1.0) driver issue (since spring uses Savepoint approach) or Oracle (11g)?

I've attached simplified (all-in-one) test to demonstrate this issue:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration({ "/core-dao-config.xml", "/test-context.xml" })
    @TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
            TransactionTest.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)

    public class TransactionTest extends AbstractTestExecutionListener
    {

    public TransactionTest(){}

    DataSource dataSource;

    DataSourceTransactionManager txManager;

    protected void injectDependencies(final TestContext testContext) throws Exception {

        dataSource = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(DataSource.class);
        txManager = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(DataSourceTransactionManager.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        injectDependencies(testContext);
        final TransactionStatus transaction = txManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionAttribute());
        testContext.setAttribute("parenttx", transaction);
    }    

    @Autowired
    SomeDao someDao;

    @Test
    public void testTx() {
        final DbObject domainObject = new DbObject();
        domainObject.setKey(-303L);
        someDao.add(domainObject);

        assertNotNull(someDao.findByKey(-303L));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInserted() {
        assertNull(someDao.findByKey(-303L));
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        final TransactionStatus parenttx =(TransactionStatus)testContext.getAttribute("parenttx");
        Validate.notNull(parenttx);
        txManager.rollback(parenttx);
    }
}
```

So when method testTx inserts the record testInserted is seeing it and FAILING. But a log says that data is rolled back:

```
00:39:09.892 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@74fbc266 testClass = TransactionTest, testInstance = TransactionTest@3c97f28a, testMethod = testTx@TransactionTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@1bb4611a testClass = TransactionTest, locations = '{classpath:/core-dao-config.xml, classpath:/test-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager@5f53002b]; rollback [true]
00:39:09.896 [main] DEBUG SomeDao - Running add using Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@34311f74]
00:39:10.456 [main] DEBUG SomeDao - Running findOne
00:39:10.458 [main] DEBUG SomeDao - Running find: gkey=(-303) using Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@34311f74]
00:39:10.752 [main] DEBUG SomeDao - <==      Total: 1
00:39:10.968 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@74fbc266 testClass = TransactionTest, testInstance = TransactionTest@3c97f28a, testMethod = testTx@TransactionTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@1bb4611a testClass = TransactionTest, locations = '{classpath:/core-dao-config.xml, classpath:/test-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
00:39:11.184 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@74fbc266 testClass = TransactionTest, testInstance = TransactionTest@3bd8bd66, testMethod = testInserted@TransactionTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@1bb4611a testClass = TransactionTest, locations = '{classpath:/core-dao-config.xml, classpath:/test-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager@5f53002b]; rollback [true]
00:39:11.187 [main] DEBUG SomeDao - Running findOne
00:39:11.187 [main] DEBUG SomeDao - Running find: gkey=(-303)
00:39:11.402 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@74fbc266 testClass = TransactionTest, testInstance = TransactionTest@3bd8bd66, testMethod = testInserted@TransactionTest, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<DbObject{row=BaseRow{rownumStr=row#(1), status=UNCHANGED, rowscn=D, rowid=AAAkSFAAcAAAQ2uAAX, creator=TEST, created=Sun Nov 30 14:38:19 EET 2014}, gkey=-303}>, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@1bb4611a testClass = TransactionTest, locations = '{classpath:/core-dao-config.xml, classpath:/test-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
```

Any thoughts?